# Replace animation callbacks with Kotlin cancellable coroutine extensions (Suspending over views)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, extension-methods, kotlin-coroutines

So I read this great Medium post by Chris Banes [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/suspending-over-views-19de9ebd7020) which explains how coroutines or specifically suspend functions can be used to coordinate animations without the "callback hell" that you can fall into when chaining animations together. I managed to get the `onAnimationEnd` listener extension working as per his example but I can't seem to do the same for the `onAnimationStart` listener, here is my `awaitEnd` method

```
suspend fun Animator.awaitEnd() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->

    continuation.invokeOnCancellation { cancel() }

    this.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        private var endedSuccessfully = true

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {

            endedSuccessfully = false
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {

            animation.removeListener(this)

            if (continuation.isActive) {
                // If the coroutine is still active...
                if (endedSuccessfully) {
                    // ...and the Animator ended successfully, resume the coroutine
                    continuation.resume(Unit)
                } else {
                    // ...and the Animator was cancelled, cancel the coroutine too
                    continuation.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    })

}
```

In the code below I'm using this in an async block and awaiting first the animation to finish and then the coroutine to finish

```
val anim = async {
    binding.splash.circleReveal(null, startAtX = x, startAtY = y).run {
        start()
        //...doStuff()
        awaitEnd()
    }
}
anim.await()
```

This works beautifully, adding logs to the correct functions shows me that everything is being called exactly as expected, now to add a started extension in the same way...

```
suspend fun Animator.started() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->

    continuation.invokeOnCancellation { cancel() }

    this.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {

        private var endedSuccessfully = true

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {
            endedSuccessfully = false
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
            Log.d("DETAIL", "Animator.started() onAnimationStart")

            animation?.removeListener(this)

            if (continuation.isActive) {
                // If the coroutine is still active...
                if (endedSuccessfully) {
                    // ...and the Animator ended successfully, resume the coroutine
                    continuation.resume(Unit)
                } else {
                    // ...and the Animator was cancelled, cancel the coroutine too
                    continuation.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and call it from the same async block after the start method (this may have something to do with things)

```
val anim = async {
    binding.splash.circleReveal(null, startAtX = x, startAtY = y).run {
        start()
        started()
        //...doStuff()
        awaitEnd()
    }
}
anim.await()
```

now what happens is the coroutine for started gets suspended but never resumes, if I add some logging statements I can see that it calls `start()`, it then calls `started()` but then doesn't go any further, obviously I've tried changing the order of operations to no avail can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

many thanks

**EDIT**

I also tried this for adding a sharedElementEnter transition but again it just will not work for me,

```
suspend fun TransitionSet.awaitTransitionEnd() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->

    val listener = object : TransitionListenerAdapter() {
        private var endedSuccessfully = true

        override fun onTransitionCancel(transition: Transition) {
            super.onTransitionCancel(transition)
            endedSuccessfully = false
        }

        override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
            super.onTransitionEnd(transition)
            Log.d("DETAIL","enterTransition onTransitionEnd")
            transition.removeListener(this)

            if (continuation.isActive) {
                // If the coroutine is still active...
                if (endedSuccessfully) {
                    // ...and the Animator ended successfully, resume the coroutine
                    continuation.resume(Unit)
                } else {
                    // ...and the Animator was cancelled, cancel the coroutine too
                    continuation.cancel()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation { removeListener(listener) }
    this.addListener(listener)

}
```

and again trying to use the await method

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    val sharedElementEnterTransitionAsync = async {
        sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(context)
            .inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_transition)
        (sharedElementEnterTransition as TransitionSet).awaitTransitionEnd()
    }
    sharedElementEnterTransitionAsync.await()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - coroutine is never resumed.

**Why?**

By the time you call `started()` method animation has already started. It means `onAnimationStart` defined in a listener within `started()` will not be called *(as it has been already called)* placing the underlying coroutine in a forever waiting state.

The same will happen if you call `started()` before `start()`: underlying coroutine will be waiting for `onAnimationStart` to be called but it will never happen because `start()` method call is blocked by the coroutine created by `started()` method.

That is almost a dead-lock.

#### Solution 1

Call `start()` before `started()` returns:

```
suspend fun Animator.started() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->

    continuation.invokeOnCancellation { cancel() }

    this.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        ...
    })

    // Before the coroutine is even returned we should start the animation
    start()
}
```

#### Solution 2

Pass in a function (that optionally takes a `CancellableContinuation<Unit>` argument):

```
suspend fun Animator.started(executeBeforeReturn: (CancellableContinuation<Unit>) -> Unit) = suspendCancellableCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->

    continuation.invokeOnCancellation { cancel() }

    this.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        ...
    })
    executeBeforeReturn(continuation)
}
```

It will allow you to:

- use the coroutine (e.g. cancel) before you even start the animation;
- avoid the lock.

Example:

```
val anim = async { 
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.ALPHA, 0f, 1f).run { 
        started { continuation ->
            if (anything) {
                continuation.cancel()
            }
            start()
        }
        awaitEnd()
    }
}
anim.await()
```

Comment: this works, many thanks used solution 1 for now but solution 2 may help with another issue i have, I've accepted your answer and will very likely be awarding you the bounty

Comment: @martinseal1987, I'm glad it helped! Any questions are welcome.

Comment: the other issue is actually the edit to the question using it for shared element transitions, the problem is that i have to start the postponed transition which i cant call from that scope so passing in a lambda is very nice thanks again

Comment: think ive gone a bit mad with this lol almost every listener is now an extension so much cleaner to read removed alot of the async blocks as i think they were unnecessary

Comment: @martinseal1987 "cleaner to read removed alot of the async blocks" - great. Just a reminder - do not overcomplicate.